# Need to convert SELECT statement with HAVING to UPDATE Set command

Tags: sql, having

How can I change the below `SELECT` statement so that it updates `SALESSTATUS = 4` and `JSDETAILEDSTATUS = 4`:

```
SELECT     
  JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER.SALESID AS PARENT, 
  SALESLINE.SALESSTATUS, 
  SALESLINE.JSDETAILEDSTATUS
FROM JSCONTINUITYCUSTLINE 
INNER JOIN JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER ON JSCONTINUITYCUSTLINE.DATAAREAID = JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER.DATAAREAID 
AND JSCONTINUITYCUSTLINE.INVENTTRANSID = JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER.INVENTTRANSID 
INNER JOIN SALESLINE ON JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER.SALESID = SALESLINE.SALESID 
AND JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER.DATAAREAID = SALESLINE.DATAAREAID 
AND JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER.INVENTTRANSID = SALESLINE.INVENTTRANSID
WHERE     
  (JSCONTINUITYCUSTLINE.DATAAREAID = N'CSN') 
  AND (JSCONTINUITYCUSTLINE.SALESID <> N' ') 
  AND (JSCONTINUITYCUSTLINE.SALESQTY <> 0) 
  AND (SALESLINE.SALESSTATUS = 1)
GROUP BY 
  JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER.SALESID, 
  SALESLINE.SALESSTATUS, 
  SALESLINE.JSDETAILEDSTATUS
HAVING
  (MAX(JSCONTINUITYCUSTLINE.STARTDATE) < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-01 00:00:00', 102))
  AND (JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER.SALESID <> N' ')
ORDER BY PARENT
```

Comment: What SQL product & version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to alias your table names.
Use NULL instead of ' ' and replace your condition `CL.SALESID IS NOT NULL`
I don't understand CH.SALESID <> N' ' in HAVING clause...

```
BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE SALESLINE
    SET
        SL.SALESSTATUS = 4, 
        SL.JSDETAILEDSTATUS = 4
    FROM
        SALESLINE SL  
        INNER JOIN JSCONTINUITYCUSTHEADER CH
            ON CL.DATAAREAID = CH.DATAAREAID AND CL.INVENTTRANSID = CH.INVENTTRANSID 
        INNER JOIN JSCONTINUITYCUSTLINE CL
            ON CH.SALESID = SL.SALESID AND CH.DATAAREAID = SL.DATAAREAID AND CH.INVENTTRANSID = SL.INVENTTRANSID
    WHERE     
        CL.DATAAREAID = N'CSN'
        AND CL.SALESID <> N' ' 
        AND CL.SALESQTY <> 0) 
        AND SL.SALESSTATUS = 1
    GROUP BY 
        CH.SALESID,
        SL.SALESSTATUS, 
        SL.JSDETAILEDSTATUS
    HAVING
        MAX(CL.STARTDATE) < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-01 00:00:00', 102)



-- Check you UPDATE is correctly performed
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Now I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'."  This is for SQL 2005 so I am not sure this will work for that version?